# Django Install Wierdness - Mac OSX 10.8.5 and Macport Python 2.7.6 - Django/Python/Unix beginner

Tags: django, python-2.7, macports

I've found a lot of posts on Macports/Django install issues but none seem to quite address my situation.

Installed Django using Macports from the command line using

> sudo port install py27-django

This seemed to work fine. I opened up IDLE and was able to import django. The following bit of code

```
import django
from django.core import management
print django.VERSION
```

returns

> (1, 5, 1, 'final', 0)

Which I take to mean I have the final version of Django 1.5.1 installed. So, all seems to be well.

However, now I switch over to my Django tutorial to get learning and I am asked to type this into the command line to confirm that Django is installed:

> python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"

and get the following error:

```
> File "<string>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named
> django
```

Some other bits of data. Here's my $PATH:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Finally, the command

> django-admin.py startproject mysite

returns

> -bash: django-admin.py: command not found

But the command

> django-admin-2.7.py startproject mysite

works (creates a new directory called mysite in the working directory). I read somehwere that Macports renames the django-admin file.

I've only been working with Unix for a few weeks so this is a bit confusing.  It seems like I have Django on my system, but perhaps the python I am trying to access from my command line is a different python from that which Macports uses.

Any help appreciated!

Dennis

Comment: Instead of using Macports why don't you just install Django via pip? E.g. pip install Django (for the latest release) or pip install Django=1.5.1 - It's a very nice way to install Django, everything is cleaned up nicely afterwards too (i.e. it will uninstall old versions and set the django-admin.py in place correctly). https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set your PYTHONPATH environment variable from your terminal to reference your django install. IDLE probably did this for you, but in another shell you'll need to set it. You can set it in your terminal permanently by setting it in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile (or whatever your terminal shell is).

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you for your quick response. Not sure how to identify which is the correct path to use when setting PYTHONPATH. And do I want to set PYTHONPATH to the folder than contains the MacPorts python program, or where Macports is storing Django files? (Perhaps these are one and the same)  When I, for example type 'locate django-admin.py

Comment: Sorry was cut off above.  Continuing...    When I, for example type 'locate django-admin.py' in to the command line, I find it at two different paths:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/django-admin.py
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH starts with `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` so when you type python you get the python in that directory which is the Apple supplied one  nut you have installed Django for the Macports one so python does not see it.

To fix you need to have /opt/local/bin earlier on the path than the /Library one. even better remove that /Library entry and use `port select python ...` to choose which python to run the Macports 2.7 or Apple's or others

As for the django-admin-2.7.py issue, Macports allows you to have several versions of python at once so code depending on eth version has the version add into the script names e.g. you could have a django-admin-2.6.py as well if you installed the py26-django package. This also applies to python itself however python also adds into the port select mechanism so you set a default version.